# How to clean a battle rope?

Tags: exercise-equipment, maintenance

I have bought my battle rope for two years, a common 38mm diameter black one and should be made by artificial fiber. It is placed on ground for 2 years.

Recently I carry it out on my shoulder, walk to the large balcony at my apartment and use it. When carrying it, I found it smells bad. Maybe because it is close to dust on ground for two years.

How do one clean a battle rope? Definitely not by washing machine. Is it hard to dry by it's size larger than normal ropes? Maybe I have to put it under sunlight for days? How does soaking it affect rope like maybe softening it?Is there anyone to share cleaning experience? Thank you!

Comment: No one washes battle rope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Battle ropes can be made from various materials—the most common being [Nylon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon), [polypropylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polypropylene), and [polyester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_terephthalate) (Dacron, Terylene, ...) And their appropriate cleaning is therefore dependent on the specific rope.

Generally speaking, however, ropes can be washed in cold or warm water with a mild detergent. They may be soaked, but should not be soaked for extended periods of time. And they should not be scrubbed or subjected to high water pressures, since it can do damage to the filaments.

Ropes should not be subjected to [acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid), [bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(chemistry))/[alkalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkali), bleaches, or solvents of any kind. Even mild acids can weaken and damage the rope badly.

After washing, ropes should be dried in the shade—that is, subjected neither to [ultraviolet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet) (UV) light nor direct heat. Nylon and polyethylene terephthalate (PET polyester) are [hygroscopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygroscopy), so it is important to dry them very thoroughly. A well-ventilated or breezy location is a good choice.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try them! Your answer is awesome.